# Processing multiple URL parameters with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Controller class set up with `@RequestMapping("/vehicle")` set at the class level. One method of this class is

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Vehicle getVehicleByRegistration(
    @RequestParam(value="doAs", required = true) String doAsUser,
    @RequestParam(value="registration", required = true) String registration) throws IOException {

    return vehicleController.getByIndex(registration, doAsUser);
}
```

and I'm sending queries to it like:

```
curl -iv localhost:8096/vehicle/?doAs=user&registration=ABC1234
```

When executed, I get a response containing:

```
"exception":"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException","message":"Required String parameter 'registration' is not present"
```

If I reverse the order of `doAs` and `registration` in the URL then the error says that `'doAs' is not present`.

If I modify the method to only take one argument (either `doAs` or `registration`) then it works fine.

What's going wrong here? I've tried using `param` in the `@RequestMapping` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Try removing the / after vehicle:

curl -iv localhost:8096/vehicle?doAs=user&registration=ABC1234

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not protecting the ampersand from the shell, which is why you're also getting other weird shell output. Put the URL in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting the url you are passing to curl, in other post I saw that the ampersant was backgrounding the job.
try:

curl -iv "localhost:8096/vehicle/?doAs=user&registration=ABC1234"